# Trying to script a .exe with launch parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to create a script what will uninstall Dell Data Protection with parameters that are specific to this .exe file.

Here is what I have minus the actual creds I would use:

```
Start-Process -Filepath C:\Programfiles (x86)\Dell\Dell Data Protection\DataSecurityUninstaller.exe" -argumentlist "CMG_DECRYPT=1 FORENSIC_ADMIN="ExampleUser" FORENSIC_PWD="Passw0rd" NOREBOOT /silent"
```

I get:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "ExampleUser" FORENSIC_PWD="Passw0rd" NOREBOOT
```

When I put this into CMD it, works. I guess I don't know how to handle the run parameters correctly.

Comment: Look at the example 7 of the cmdlet, each argument is separated by commas, meaning the argumentlist should be an array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 2):

Either of these should be working:

```
Start-Process -Filepath 'C:\Programfiles (x86)\Dell\Dell Data Protection\DataSecurityUninstaller.exe' -ArgumentList 'CMG_DECRYPT=1 FORENSIC_ADMIN="ExampleUser" FORENSIC_PWD="Passw0rd" NOREBOOT /silent'
```

```
Start-Process -Filepath 'C:\Programfiles (x86)\Dell\Dell Data Protection\DataSecurityUninstaller.exe' -ArgumentList 'CMG_DECRYPT=1', 'FORENSIC_ADMIN="ExampleUser"', 'FORENSIC_PWD="Passw0rd"', 'NOREBOOT', '/silent'
```

You're opening `"` here `"CMG` then closing here `_ADMIN="` which leads to the cmdlet thinking you're giving `ExampleUser...` as the input of a different parameter, hence the error.

Also, you may just want to run the uninstaller from your current session, and `Start-Process` would not be needed in this case. I believe it would look like this:

```
& 'C:\Programfiles (x86)\Dell\Dell Data Protection\DataSecurityUninstaller.exe' CMG_DECRYPT=1 FORENSIC_ADMIN="ExampleUser" FORENSIC_PWD="Passw0rd" NOREBOOT /silent
```

Comment: That's interesting that the first example works

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i'm not 100% sure it will work, but if something like this works (2 arguments on 1 string) `Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -WindowStyle Maximized'` I don't see why wouldn't the other one work.

Comment: Makes sense to me.